# How can I make a loop to generate images infinite time to make a movie clip?

Tags: c#, image, loops, bitmap, switch-statement

I have a question about how can I make a loop that runs a piece of code infinite time? Basically I have a peace of code that uses random function to create a pixelate bitmap image and display it to my image box to the user interface. 
However I am having difficulty when I need to execute that piece of code in order to generate images simultaneously and continually to be played after each other in order to make a video clip of those images. I have used “while (true)” loop but it doesn’t show anything on my screen and my programme just crashes each time I run the code.
Can anyone tell me how can I make a very smooth loop which executes my code in millisecond interval?

```
While (true)
{
    foreach (Point p in blackPixels)
    {
       if (r.NextDouble() < 0.20)
       {
           bmp.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, Color.Black);
       }
       else
       {
           bmp.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, Color.White);
       }
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Comment: Use recursion within your alogorithm. But even that has an ending criteria (it is not infinite). Also you need to look more into memory management with recursion.

Comment: You aren't updating your UI at any point either.  Your code is generating the new image, but never updating the front end.

Comment: Neil Knight, could you please explain clearer what do you mean by that? i am using "pictureBox1.Image = bmp;" each time, so it should update my out put!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this code on the UI thread, nothing will be displayed because your while loop blocks the thread. You will need to place your code in a separate thread or task.

Comment: does any one have any practical solution?!